# iText v 7 error, "classes can only inherit from other classes" at "Inherits IDocumentReadyListener"

Tags: vb.net, itext7

How do I solve the error of "classes can only inherit from other classes" at "Inherits IDocumentReadyListener"? This is in VB.net using iText v7 api. I am trying to get the bytearray from the pdf splitter.

```
Class ByteArrayPdfSplitter
    Inherits iText.Kernel.Utils.PdfSplitter

    Private currentOutputStream As MemoryStream

    Public Sub New(ByVal pdfDocument As iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument)
        MyBase.New(pdfDocument)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function GetNextPdfWriter(ByVal documentPageRange As iText.Kernel.Utils.PageRange) As iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter
        currentOutputStream = New MemoryStream()
        Return New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(currentOutputStream)
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property CurrentMemoryStream As MemoryStream
        Get
            Return currentOutputStream
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Class DocumentReadyListender
        Inherits IDocumentReadyListener

        Private splitter As ByteArrayPdfSplitter

        Public Sub New(ByVal splitter As ByteArrayPdfSplitter)
            Me.splitter = splitter
        End Sub

        Public Sub DocumentReady(ByVal pdfDocument As iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument, ByVal pageRange As iText.Kernel.Utils.PageRange)
            pdfDocument.Close()
            Dim contents As Byte() = splitter.CurrentMemoryStream.ToArray()
            Dim pageNumber As String = pageRange.ToString()
        End Sub
    End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IDocumentReadyListener` is not a class, it's an *interface*, and whenever you *implement* an interface, the correct key word to indicate this is `Implements`, not `Inherits`. Thus:

```
Public Class DocumentReadyListender
        Implements IDocumentReadyListener
```

For some more backgrounds on interfaces read for example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/interfaces/).

Comment: Thanks mkl! I am so noob!

Comment: Telerik code converter puts inherits instead of implements.